# How to generate Facebook User Access Token using curl

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl

I am doing a project where I need to import Facebook Page feeds. For accessing Facebook page feeds, I need a page_access_token and to generate page_access_token I need User access token.

Here my question is

1.How to generate this User_access_token using CURL ? Most of the  solution requires APP_KEY & APP_SECRET. Is it not possible to get user_access_token without any APP ?

2. Once I get the User_access_token how do I use it to get Page access Token using CURL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can´t get ANY Token without an App, but you don´t need to program anything in order to get a User Token. These articles explain everything in detail:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

For example, you can use the [API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to select your App and generate User Tokens.

Comment: If I provide the app credentials like APP_KEY & APP_SECRET to get access_token, then that access token will be called app_access_token right? If I provide the app credentials, how will it become user_access_token? what makes it a user_access_token ?

Comment: yes. select your app in the api explorer and click "get access token" to get a user token. you need to authorize the app for that.

Comment: Ok I got it. But is there a way I can get user_access_token programmatically using CURL ? I am not supposed to use the Facebook-php-sdk or any other libraries

Comment: ok here I got from the above links you gave. By making call to me/accounts right ? Now, do I need to use this user_access_token to get the page_access_token? If yes, how ?

Comment: everything you need to know is explained very well in the links in my answer, and in the facebook docs. you need to take your time reading ;)

Answer (score 0):

### Wrong question, No tokens are needed

I just tried it and it took me less than 5 minutes, never having scraped FB in the past. I saved the page to my Server and brought up the page using my URL and it looked just like if I were on FB.

If a Browser can load the page with JavaScript disabled, then you can too.

You have to use https://m.facebook.com/, JavaScript is not required on their mobile site.

What you want to do, is not difficult at all.

Just go there in your Browser and copy the cookies key values into the `Cookie:` HTTP request header. Mine are x'ed out.

```
<?php
$request = array();
$request[] = 'Host: m.facebook.com';
$request[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0';
$request[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
$request[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5';
$request[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate';
$request[] = 'DNT: 1';
$request[] = 'Cookie: datr=x; fr=x; lu=x s=xx; csm=x; xs=xx; c_user=x; p=-2; act=x; presence=x; noscript=1';
$request[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$request[] = 'Pragma: no-cache';
$request[] = 'ache-Control: no-cache';
$url = 'https://m.facebook.com/';
 $ch = curl_init($url);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,100);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);

  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  if (curl_errno($ch)){
      $data .= 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
  }
  else {
    $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
    $responseHeader = substr($data,0,$skip);
    $data= substr($data,$skip);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $info = var_export($info,true);
   }
      while(true){  // get cookies from response header
        $s = strpos($head,'Set-Cookie: ',$e);
        if (!$s){break;}
        $s += 12;
        $e = strpos($head,';',$s);
        $cookie = substr($head,$s,$e-$s) ;
        $s = strpos($cookie,'=');
        $key = substr($cookie,0,$s);
        $value = substr($cookie,$s);
        $cookies[$key] = $value;

      }

     $cookie = '';  // format cookies for next request header
     $show = '';
     $head = '';
     $delim = '';
     foreach ($cookies as $k => $v){
       $cookie .= "$delim$k$v";
       $delim = '; ';
     }

  $fp = fopen("fb.html",'w');
  fwrite($fp,"$data\n$info\n$responseHeader");
  fclose($fp);

readfile('fb.html');
```

Comment: I need page_access_token to post anything to Facebook page as page(not user). To get a page_access_token, I need user_Access_token.
[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens]

Comment: To post, you could log in, and post.correct?  If so, it is very easy to do it with curl.